# Webapps link missing in SU

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

I can't see [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) link in super user screen bottom section.

Same link is present SO, API/Apps. Even serverfault doesn't have this link?

I'm not sure about bug tag, still i'm making this question tag as bug.

Please retag if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO now has Web Apps and Gaming links, but SU (which would be the largest source of questions from the original trilogy sites) doesn't.

The new sites have the "full" footer with all the non-beta sites listed.

Server Fault hasn't been updated either.

Comment: Reported to [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66871/web-apps-and-gaming-links-missing-from-footer-on-super-user-and-server-fault) as it's not just a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought since Webapps is not part of the "Trilogy", the links are not available. SO & SU are on the same SVN revision, so I'm not exactly sure why Webapps link is not available.

Comment: SO has webapps link, while SU and SF has doctype. So 'Trilogy' not consistent here.